# Fast Text matching in Python

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I need to do text matching over a large number of strings (between each pair) and find the overlapping subsequences.I wanted to know if the knuth morris pratt algorithm will be best for this job, considering that I want this functionality in Python and it should be scalable over a large set of string ? I am looking for advice like if this is the best way to go about it or is there any better way to do string matching that is both scalable and efficient ?

Comment: "re" module for regular expression operations , the "re.match()" and "re.search()" methods might help. Anyway be more clear on what you exactly need.

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR:** scalable + efficient = RegEx.

First of all I recommend you to read: [Regular Expression Matching Can Be Simple And Fast](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).

*RegEx* would probably be the most scalable solution since it's not just for matching, but also provide possibility of group-capturing and back-referencing.

Furthermore the Python's `re` module is written in C and will probably be faster than most of the code you'll write yourself in Python.

For simple substring searching you could use Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm indeed but when it comes to real-world words and phrases (which are not so repetitive), you could find that *RegEx* is better on average.